# Hidden columns dont show well when filter is applied

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

I have a simple primefaces filter datatable with some columns hidden (using diplay none). All works great. When I apply a filter that selects no rows (i filter some ID that doesnt exist) the columns start to look really weird. The hidden columns start taking space. I recently updated to primefaces 5.0

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I think I am getting close. The problem it is that when the emptyMessage it is generated, it has a colspan of 65 the total columns (including the hidden ones). Thats the problem. If I modify with firefox the colspan to 5 it works great. Anyone knows where primefaces generates that colspan?

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-empty-message">

<td colspan="65"></td>

</tr>
```

That colspan it is the one I need to edit. I am studying the primefaces source code to try to fix it.

Comment: I'm currently looking into this. Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: try PF 5.1 and/or 5.2-SNAPSHOT to see if there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the columns does not work. Instead try a 0px width. I created a class I use specifically on 'hidden' columns. exportOnly

I also had to apply other style for other browser quirks. Not an ideal solution but does the trick.

```
    .ui-datatable thead th.exportOnly, 
    .ui-datatable tbody td.exportOnly, 
    .ui-datatable tfoot td.exportOnly {
        width: 0px !important;
        visibility: collapse !important;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the CSS class like this:

```
.ui-helper-hidden {
    width: 0px !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
}
```

It's a workaround, but it works for me.